# Dos Batch Script - Recursively replace file instance with master file (timthumb exploit prevention)

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I've found a few really good examples, but not quite what I need. My goal is to have a batch script that I can run nightly to replace all instances of a file (in my case timthumb.php) with a fresh copy of the file located at the root of the drive.

Here's what I have so far...

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b C:\thumb_test') do copy /y C:\thumb_test\timthumb.php %%a
```

This is as close as I've come, it will replace instances of timthumb.php in folders such as C:\thumb_test\test1\timthumb.php, but will not go deeper into directories. For example C:\thumb_test\test2\level2\timthumb.php was not replaced. Also, after replacing the files it looks like it's attempting to read the actual timthumb.php and outputs a bunch of errors for example...

```
C:\thumb_test>by Tim McDaniels and Darren Hoyt
'by' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found /R for recursive, but when I try the following it doesn't work either.

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b C:\thumb_test') do copy /y C:\thumb_test\timthumb.php %%a
```

This gives me the result:
    C:\thumb_test>test.bat
    %a was unexpected at this time.

```
C:\thumb_test>for /r /f %a IN ('dir /b C:\thumb_test') do copy /y C:\thumb_test\
timthumb.php %a
```

My DOS knowledge is limited, so I'm hoping one of the experts out there has an idea.

Thanks
-Sam

PS for anyone using timthumb, you should take a look at http://markmaunder.com/2011/08/01/zero-day-vulnerability-in-many-wordpress-themes/ and make sure you're site is secured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /R c:\thumb_test %%a in (timthumb.php) do if exist "%%a" copy /y c:\thumb_test\timthumb.php "%%a"
```

or, using the more reliable robocopy instead of copy:

```
for /R c:\thumb_test %%a in (.) do robocopy /xl c:\thumb_test "%%a" timthumb.php
```

Comment: I went with the 2nd option (robocopy) and it seems to work perfect. I'm going to be testing it more locally and then trying it on our development server. 
Thank you Harry

Comment: After some more testing this works correctly, but it makes all of the folders and files (where the replacement is happening) hidden and system files, where I can no longer uncheck the "hidden" property. Is there a way to keep the settings of the folders and files intact? Thanks

Comment: By default robocopy copies the attributes from the source, so I assume the source folder and file are hidden and system?  You can override this by specifying /copy:dt if the version of robocopy is recent enough.  (Type robocopy /??? for usage information.)